# UpdateItemResponse.ReturnedItem is null from Exchange Server

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I am able to update the contacts, but I would like to know if with some contact happens a error, to know which ExchId happens the error, but ReturnedItem is null. is it possible to populate this info ?

ServiceResponseCollection  responses= service.UpdateItems(lstContacts, objContactSyncFolderID, ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite, null, null);

```
        var ltError = responses.Where(uiRes => uiRes.Result == ServiceResult.Error).ToList();


        foreach (var item in ltError)
        {
            string ExchId = item.ReturnedItem.Id.UniqueId; ///
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When using any of the batch operation in EWS the responses come back in the order you submitted them, so if you want to correlate request to response you just need to look at the collection you submitted eg element 4 in the collection lstContacts will correlate to element 4 in the responses.

Cheers
Glen